# Выказывать или высказывать?

Tags: лексика

Выказывать или выСказывать заинтересованность?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите показать, сделать явной - то выказывать, выказать заинтересованность (это можно и молча).
Если хотите сказать о заинтересованности - то высказать, высказывать. 
Т.е. **Выказывать** - 1. показывать, делать видимым. 2.выставлять напоказ.
**Высказывать** - выражать словами, говорить.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что словосочетание "высказывать заинтересованность" как-то "не звучит". Можно высказать вопрос, замечание, мнение. То есть то, что говорится. А разве заинтересованность - это слова?

Answer (score 0):

Согласна, "Высказать заинтересованность" как-то несуразно. Лучше тогда уже "проявить заинтересованность".